# How to check if is there a value in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, any

I would like to check if is there any value different than zero and different than NaN in a dataframe column. I was using the following method but is not working quite right now.

```
if ts.any((ts['x'] > 0) || (ts['x'] < 0)):
   bool = True
```

**or**

```
if ts.any((ts['x'] > 0) || (ts['x'] < 0)):
   bool = True
```

Any tips of how should I proceed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `|` for bitwise `OR` or `&` for bitwise `AND` with [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.any.html):

```
if ((ts['x'] > 0) | (ts['x'] < 0)).any():
```

Or:

```
if ((ts['x'] != 0) & (ts['x'].notnull())).any():
```

Comment: I test it a lot and need in second solution `&` for `AND` instead `|` for `OR`